# How to change colour of certain elements of a matrix in matplotlib matshow?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matplotlib

I have an adjacency matrix of a bipartite graph (of 1's and 0's) and bi-clusters (array of arrays of rows and columns) for this matrix. How do I set different colours for elements (only 1's) in adjacency matrix which belong to different clusters with matplotlib matshow?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a_matrix = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0 ,0]])
cluster_1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]])
cluster_2 = np.array([[4, 5], [1, 2]])

# plot matrix with one colour
plt.matshow(a_matrix, cmap='Greys', interpolation='nearest')
```

**Adjacency matrix, bi-clusters, and a bipartite graph:**

[image: adjacency matrix, bi-clusters, and a bipartite graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach might be to make a copy of your matrix and then give distinct values to the clusters you identify.

```
m = a_matrix.copy()     # a copy we can change without altering the orignal
c = cluster_1           # an alias to save typing

# Naked NumPy doesn't seem to have a cartesian product, so roll our own
for i in range(c.shape[1]):
    for j in range(c.shape[1]):
        if m[c[0,i]-1,c[1,j]-1]:
            m[c[0,i]-1,c[1,j]-1] = 2

plt.matshow(m, cmap='jet', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

[image]

For more clusters, loop over the above, setting a distinct value for each cluster (and maybe choose or define a better colormap). I'm sure there are more efficient implementations of the cartesian product as well...

Comment: Thank you for answering! It works. By the way, I found implementations of the cartesian product in sklearn.
    `sklearn.utils.extmath import cartesian`