# Graphical representation of ternary matrix in Python

Tags: python, matrix, representation

I need to graphically represent a ternary matrix (matrix with exactly three distinct values) in Python.

**Input**: Ternary matrix (entries are 0, 1 or 2)

**Expected graphical output**: A matrix layout which uses different colors to represent different numbers in the matrix

Example:
[Sample matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK7I4.png)

Expected Output:
[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMeKA.png)

How should I go about getting this output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change colour of certain elements of a matrix in matplotlib matshow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35379073/how-to-change-colour-of-certain-elements-of-a-matrix-in-matplotlib-matshow)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Would `matplotlib`'s `imshow()` work for you, or is there something more you would like to get?

Comment: Thanks @RahulAgarwal and norok2. Both the answers are helpful.